# Modem and speedtest have wildly different speeds

Tags: networking

Modem shows that speed is about 5Mbps, speed test does not cross 150kbps, I pay for a speed of 2Mbps. What exactly is happening. And how can I rectify my Internet speeds. My ISP is BSNL and I have a landline+broadband connection. My modem+router is DLink2730U.

What I have tried so far:

1. Wireless and wired both media. Show similar results regardless of distance
2. Lodging a complaint with the ISP. Well they replaced their wires and phone line and whatnots. But speeds remain low
3. Tried Wi-Fi with my phone. Still very low speed
4. Speed test with sites like Google's l, Ookla, fast.com show similar depressing results

**Update**

I tried using elementary OS for internet speeds when a startling revelation came to light.  Apparently the terminal downloads (apt upgrade and apt install) work just fine but web browser is slow AF. Is it possible for ISP to somehow knowingly/unknowingly slow down web browser but leave the terminal unaffected.

Comment: Which speed test site are you visiting? Are you connected to the router via a LAN cable or wireless? If wired, what's the signal strength like? If wired, how long is the cable? There are a LOT of things that can impact a speed test, you shouldn't expect to get modem speeds on every piece of hardware you connect to the router.

Comment: @spikey_richie. I have tried both wireless and wired. Both show depressingly low internet speeds

Comment: *Modem shows that speed is about 5Mbps* It is physical connection speed. Traffic transfer must be lower because of some service data transfer. *speed test does not cross 150kbps, I pay for a speed of 2Mbps.* Provider cannot be responsible for the external resource and its access channels. Test transfer speed in the provider's area of responsibility (for example, some provider's FTP server). Or call its technical support and ask them "come to me and show me 2Mbps for which I pay"...

Comment: Who is your Telco, what modem/router do you have and do you know the access technology?

Comment: It's quite possible for the ISP to proxy http/https in some way that's slow, while other protocols are not proxied and work faster. It may also depend on routing and destination. It has nothing to do with web browser via terminal (other than the web browser normally uses http/https).

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely being scammed by your ISP who may be giving you 5 megabit access speeds, but overcontending their uplinks. Unfortunately this is difficult to prove.

The first thing I would do would be to eliminate the possibility of WIFI issues by disconnecting WIFI and connecting up using a cable. If this fixes the problem you know that you live in a noisy (to wifi) area or have bad equipment and its possibly not the ISPs fault - or if it is their fault it's at your home premises router.

The next thing to do is to have wifi disabled on router and try 1 connection at a time in case one of your systems is compromised and chewing your bandwidth.

If this does not solve the problem download and run WinMTR or similar and run some tests over a fair (mins - hours) and also different sites duration - Experienced admins can often interpret this data to point to bottlenecks and next-steps - but there are lots of variables like latency,jitter, packet loss, routes - learning to interpret these is part science, part guesswork, part art.

Another "hard ask" is to install dd-wrt on your router (or another router ALL your traffic is funnelled through ) which can show you usage graphs and give you more visibility if what you think is happening is actually the case.

Unfortunately if it is a Telco issue you may be up for a fight few people have the skill and facts to win - although I so happen to be one of them. It's a long, hard battle and it may well be easier to change ISPs if that is the case.